# Debug a custom Pipeline Transformer in Flink

Tags: scala, debugging, apache-flink, pipeline

I am trying to implement a custom Transformer in Flink following indications in [its documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/libs/ml/pipelines.html#how-to-implement-a-pipeline-operator) but when I try to executed it seems the `fit` operation is never being called.  Here it is what I've done so far:

```
class InfoGainTransformer extends Transformer[InfoGainTransformer] {

  import InfoGainTransformer._

  private[this] var counts: Option[collection.immutable.Vector[Map[Key, Double]]] = None

  // here setters for params, as Flink does

}

object InfoGainTransformer {

  // ====================================== Parameters =============================================
  // ...

  // ==================================== Factory methods ==========================================
  // ...

  // ========================================== Operations =========================================

  implicit def fitLabeledVectorInfoGain = new FitOperation[InfoGainTransformer, LabeledVector] {
    override def fit(instance: InfoGainTransformer, fitParameters: ParameterMap, input: DataSet[LabeledVector]): Unit = {
      val counts = collection.immutable.Vector[Map[Key, Double]]()
      input.map {
        v =>
          v.vector.map {
            case (i, value) =>
              println("INSIDE!!!")
              val key = Key(value, v.label)
              val cval = counts(i).getOrElse(key, .0)
              counts(i) + (key -> cval)
          }
      }
    }
  }

  implicit def fitVectorInfoGain[T <: Vector] = new FitOperation[InfoGainTransformer, T] {
    override def fit(instance: InfoGainTransformer, fitParameters: ParameterMap, input: DataSet[T]): Unit = {
      input
    }
  }

  implicit def transformLabeledVectorsInfoGain = {
    new TransformDataSetOperation[InfoGainTransformer, LabeledVector, LabeledVector] {
      override def transformDataSet(
                                     instance: InfoGainTransformer,
                                     transformParameters: ParameterMap,
                                     input: DataSet[LabeledVector]): DataSet[LabeledVector] = input
    }
  }

  implicit def transformVectorsInfoGain[T <: Vector : BreezeVectorConverter : TypeInformation : ClassTag] = {
    new TransformDataSetOperation[InfoGainTransformer, T, T] {
      override def transformDataSet(instance: InfoGainTransformer, transformParameters: ParameterMap, input: DataSet[T]): DataSet[T] = input
    }
  }
}
```

Then I tried to use it in two ways:

```
val scaler = StandardScaler()
val polyFeatures = PolynomialFeatures()
val mlr = MultipleLinearRegression()
val gain = InfoGainTransformer().setK(2)

// Construct the pipeline
val pipeline = scaler
  .chainTransformer(polyFeatures)
  .chainTransformer(gain)
  .chainPredictor(mlr)

val r = pipeline.predict(dataSet map (_.vector))
r.print()
```

And only my transformer:

```
pipeline.fit(dataSet)
```

In both cases, when I set a breakpoint inside `fitLabeledVectorInfoGain`, for example in the line `input.map`, the debugger stops there, but if I also set a breakpoint inside the nested map, for example bellow `println("INSIDE!!!")`, it never stops there.

Does anyone knows how could I debug this custom transformer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems its working now. I think what was happening was I wasn't implementing right the `FitOperation` because nothing was being saved in the instance state, this is the implementation now:

```
implicit def fitLabeledVectorInfoGain = new FitOperation[InfoGainTransformer, LabeledVector] {
    override def fit(instance: InfoGainTransformer, fitParameters: ParameterMap, input: DataSet[LabeledVector]): Unit = {
      //      val counts = collection.immutable.Vector[Map[Key, Double]]()
      val r = input.map {
        v =>
          v.vector.foldLeft(Map.empty[Key, Double]) {
            case (m, (i, value)) =>
              println("INSIDE fit!!!")
              val key = Key(value, v.label)
              val cval = m.getOrElse(key, .0) + 1.0
              m + (key -> cval)
          }
      }
      instance.counts = Some(r)
    }
  }
```

Now the debugger enters correctly in all breakpoints and the `TransformOperation` its also being called.